# Object key is string, but blank in the string disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

Hello I have a question about the key of object in JS

My backend side (ruby on rails) pass a object through the API like this:

```
{
  "Japan": [1, 2],
  "Korea, South":[1, 2, 3]
}
```

However, when I fetch the data in the frontend, the blank in the ket has missed, and the result become:

```
{
  "Japan": [1, 2],
  "Korea,South": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

You can see that the blank between the comma and South disappeared
I have no clue how can I fix this, does anyone have idea?

try to log the data in backend and it's correct with the blank

Comment: The content received in an AJAX request will not be transformed by JS unless it's been instructed to. This means that you either have some JS intercepting/amending the value in the AJAX request, or your Ruby code has some middleware which changes the response before it's sent. You can easily debug this by checking the value on both the client and server side to find the discrepancy.

Comment: Are you using "Content-Type":  application/json ?